# Spark groupby filter sorting with top 3 read articles each city

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table data like following :

```
+-----------+--------+-------------+
| City Name |  URL   |  Read Count |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
| Gurgaon   |  URL1  |  3          |
| Gurgaon   |  URL3  |  6          |
| Gurgaon   |  URL6  |  5          |
| Gurgaon   |  URL4  |  1          |
| Gurgaon   |  URL5  |  5          |
| Delhi     |  URL3  |  4          |
| Delhi     |  URL7  |  2          |
| Delhi     |  URL5  |  1          |
| Delhi     |  URL6  |  6          |
| Punjab    |  URL6  |  5          |
| Punjab    |  URL4  |  1          |
| Mumbai    |  URL5  |  5          |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

I would like to see somthing like -> Top 3 Read article(if exists) each city

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| City Name |  URL   |  Count |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| Gurgaon   |  URL3  |      6 |
| Gurgaon   |  URL6  |      5 |
| Gurgaon   |  URL5  |      5 |
| Delhi     |  URL6  |      6 |
| Delhi     |  URL3  |      4 |
| Delhi     |  URL1  |      3 |
| Punjab    |  URL6  |      5 |
| Punjab    |  URL4  |      1 |
| Mumbai    |  URL5  |      5 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I am working on Spark 2.0.2, Scala 2.11.8

Comment: Sort the data by read count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are probably the way to go, and there is a built-in function for this purpose:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{rank, desc}

val window = Window.partitionBy($"City").orderBy(desc("Count"))
val dfTop = df.withColumn("rank", rank.over(window)).where($"rank" <= 3)
```

Comment: Oh whoops.  This is essentially the same as Rajat Mishra's answer, except his ignores ties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function to get the output.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("Gurgaon","URL1",3), ("Gurgaon","URL3",6), ("Gurgaon","URL6",5), ("Gurgaon","URL4",1),("Gurgaon","URL5",5)
  ("DELHI","URL3",4), ("DELHI","URL7",2), ("DELHI","URL5",1), ("DELHI","URL6",6),("Mumbai","URL5",5)
  ("Punjab","URL6",6), ("Punjab","URL4",1))).toDF("City", "URL", "Count")

df.show()

+-------+----+-----+
|   City| URL|Count|
+-------+----+-----+
|Gurgaon|URL1|    3|
|Gurgaon|URL3|    6|
|Gurgaon|URL6|    5|
|Gurgaon|URL4|    1|
|Gurgaon|URL5|    5|
|  DELHI|URL3|    4|
|  DELHI|URL7|    2|
|  DELHI|URL5|    1|
|  DELHI|URL6|    6|
| Mumbai|URL5|    5|
| Punjab|URL6|    6|
| Punjab|URL4|    1|
+-------+----+-----+

val w = Window.partitionBy($"City").orderBy($"Count".desc)
val dfTop = df.withColumn("row", rowNumber.over(w)).where($"row" <= 3).drop("row")

dfTop.show

+-------+----+-----+
|   City| URL|Count|
+-------+----+-----+
|Gurgaon|URL3|    6|
|Gurgaon|URL6|    5|
|Gurgaon|URL5|    5|
| Mumbai|URL5|    5|
|  DELHI|URL6|    6|
|  DELHI|URL3|    4|
|  DELHI|URL7|    2|
| Punjab|URL6|    6|
| Punjab|URL4|    1|
+-------+----+-----+
```

Output tested on Spark 1.6.2